# Obtain the number of backlinks from the Bing API

Tags: hyperlink, bing-api

Is there a way to get the number of backlinks for a specific domain using the Bing API?

I'd like to implement some kind of automatic popularity index for websites/domains.

Answer (score 4):

You can get google back links using their API.

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:test.com

Then parsing the JSON -> responseData -> cursor -> estimatedResultCount will get you backing count.

Comment: Any solution for bing?

Comment: I don't think that's the right figure. Your source says test.com has 3250 backlinks, while other reputable sources report 1,600,000 backlinks. https://ahrefs.com/site-explorer/overview/subdomains/test.com

Comment: This is not giving a count of the backlinks. It is simply giving you details of the results if you went to google and searched "site:test.com".

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo has deleted Site Explorer and I don't think Google supplies this data to the public.

However, Ahrefs, Moz, MajesticSEO and other crawlers do provide this data.